# Servlet mapping 2 url variable

Tags: java, servlets, url-pattern

I'm using servlet java and mapping this in web.xml.
I'm trying something like this

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>walmart-freight</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>walmart.Freight</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>walmart-freight</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/walmart/x/code/*/sku/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But does not find url mapped.

request example: /walmart/x/code/123/sku/457 method=getstrong text

Comment: did you specify "walmart-freight" in web.xml?

Comment: Not all regex are allowed in mapping. Only concrete mappings vor something like APP/* is allowed. Write a servlet which matches all and delegate the request according to the url

Comment: I can just do something like <url-pattern>/walmart/x/code/*</url-pattern> ?

Comment: @user1021323 yes. But in the servlet you can check the URL against a regex and delegate it to the correct servlet.